# Selenium fails to load elements, despite EC, waits, and scrolling attempts

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

With the Selenium (3.141), BeautifulSoup (4.7.9), and  Python (3.79), I'm trying to scrape what streaming, rental, and buying options are available for a given movie/show.  I've spent hours trying to solve this, so any help would be appreciated.  Apologies for the poor formatting, in terms of mixing in comments and prior attempts.

Example Link:  https://www.justwatch.com/us/tv-show/24

Desired Outcome is a Beautiful soup element that I can then parse (e.g., which streaming services have it, how many seasons are available, etc.),
which has 3 elements (as of now) - Hulu, IMDB TV, and DirecTV.

I tried numerous variations, but only get one of the 3 streaming services for the example link, and even then it's not a consistent result.  Often, I get an empty object.
Some of the things that I've tried included waiting for an expected condition (presence or visibility), explicitly using sleep() from the time library.  I'm using a Mac (but running Linux via a USB), so there is no "PAGE DOWN" on the physical keyboard.  For the keys module, I've tried control+arrow down, page down, and and space (space bar), but on this particular web page they don't work.  However, if I'm browsing it in a normal fashion, control+arrow down and space bar help scrolling the desired section into view.  As far as I know, there is no fn + arrow down option that works in Keys, but that's another way that I can move in a normal fashion.

I've run both headless and regular options to try to debug, as well as trying both Firefox and Chrome drivers.

Here's my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.add_argument('--enable-javascript') # double-checking to make sure that javascript is enabled
firefox_options.add_argument('--headless')
firefox_driver_path = 'geckodriver'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefox_driver_path, options=firefox_options)

url_link = 'https://www.justwatch.com/us/tv-show/24'
driver.get(url_link) # initial page
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

*Examples of things I've tried around this part of the code*

various time.sleep(3) and driver.implicitly_wait(3) commands
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.SPACE).perform()

*This code yields a timeout error when used*

stream_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
stream_results.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
(By.CLASS_NAME, "price-comparison__grid__row price-comparison__grid__row--stream")))

```
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser') # 'lxml' didn't work either
```

*Here's code for getting the html related to the streaming services.  I've also tried to grab the html code at various levels, ids, and classes of the tree, but the code just isn't there*

```
stream_row = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'price-comparison__grid__row price-comparison__grid__row--stream'})
stream_row_holder = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'price-comparison__grid__row__holder'})
stream_items = stream_row_holder\
                    .find_all('div', attrs={'class':'price-comparison__grid__row__element__icon'})
                    
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are saying your code works in some cases or not at all, but I use chrome and the four `find_all()` lines at the end all produce results. If this isn't what you mean, let me know. The one thing you may be missing is a `time.sleep()` that is long enough. That could be the only difference...

Note you need chromedriver to run this code, but perhaps you have chrome and can download chromedriver.exe.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

url = 'https://www.justwatch.com/us/tv-show/24'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

soup.find_all(class_="price-comparison__grid__row__price")
soup.find_all(class_="price-comparison__grid__row__holder")
soup.find_all(class_="price-comparison__grid__row__element__icon")
soup.find_all(class_="price-comparison__grid__row--stream")
```

This is the output from the last line:

```
[<div class="price-comparison__grid__row price-comparison__grid__row--stream"><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__title price-comparison__promoted__title"> Stream </div><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__holder"><!-- --><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__element"><div class="presentation-type price-comparison__grid__row__element__icon"><a href="https://click.justwatch.com/a?r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hulu.com%2Fwatch%2F97e1a3fe-f313-44c7-978c-23537db1bab9&amp;cx=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&amp;uct_country=US&amp;uct_buybox=special&amp;sid=" target="_blank"><img alt="Hulu" class="jw-provider-icon price-comparison__grid__row__icon" src="https://images.justwatch.com/icon/116305230/s100" title="Hulu"/><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__price"> 9 Seasons <span class="price-comparison__badge price-comparison__badge--hd price-comparison__badge--hd"> HD </span></div></a></div></div><!-- --></div></div>,
 <div class="price-comparison__grid__row price-comparison__grid__row--stream"><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__title"> Stream </div><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__holder"><!-- --><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__element"><div class="presentation-type price-comparison__grid__row__element__icon"><a href="https://click.justwatch.com/a?r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.hulu.com%2Fwatch%2F97e1a3fe-f313-44c7-978c-23537db1bab9&amp;cx=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&amp;uct_country=US&amp;uct_buybox=normal&amp;sid=" target="_blank"><img alt="Hulu" class="jw-provider-icon price-comparison__grid__row__icon" src="https://images.justwatch.com/icon/116305230/s100" title="Hulu"/><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__price"> 9 Seasons <span class="price-comparison__badge price-comparison__badge--hd price-comparison__badge--hd"> HD </span></div></a></div></div><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__element"><div class="presentation-type price-comparison__grid__row__element__icon"><a href="https://click.justwatch.com/a?r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftv%2Fwatch%2Ftt0502165&amp;cx=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&amp;uct_country=US&amp;uct_buybox=normal&amp;sid=" target="_blank"><img alt="IMDb TV" class="jw-provider-icon price-comparison__grid__row__icon" src="https://images.justwatch.com/icon/134049674/s100" title="IMDb TV"/><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__price"> 8 Seasons <!-- --></div></a></div></div><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__element"><div class="presentation-type price-comparison__grid__row__element__icon"><a href="https://click.justwatch.com/a?r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.directv.com%2Ftv%2FThe-Last-24-bGF0SVVYTWtqR1NGby9GckxSaXJvUT09%2FSomebody-Knows-Something-Vm9TYUoxOW1hN1grZFAvTTlPKzdXdz09&amp;cx=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&amp;uct_country=US&amp;uct_buybox=normal&amp;sid=" target="_blank"><img alt="DIRECTV" class="jw-provider-icon price-comparison__grid__row__icon" src="https://images.justwatch.com/icon/158260222/s100" title="DIRECTV"/><div class="price-comparison__grid__row__price"> 1 Season <span class="price-comparison__badge price-comparison__badge--hd price-comparison__badge--hd"> HD </span></div></a></div></div><!-- --></div></div>]
```

Comment: many thanks.  And yes, my post was a bit confusing.  Some of the code was working, but not everything.  Thanks to your guidance, I got it working with chromedriver.  It also occurred to me that NoScript (javascript blocker that I have installed in Firefox) may been conflicting with geckodriver somehow.  My other scrap projects haven't had problems with geckodriver, but I'm just happy it's working now.